# Laplace transform and IVP at $\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Solving the following differential equation 
$$ty^{''}\left ( t \right )+\left ( t-1 \right )y^{'}\left ( t \right )-y\left ( t \right )=0$$
with initial values $$y\left ( 0 \right )=5, y\left ( \infty \right )=0$$
I suspect the identity $$\lim _{t\rightarrow \infty}y\left ( t \right )=\lim _{s\rightarrow 0}sF\left ( s \right )  \left    ( * \right )$$
where $s$ is a complex varaible would be of help here. But for the Laplace transform of the second derivative we need the initial value of the first  derivative. Can we somehow obtain that value using equation $\left ( * \right )$?

Comment: If it helps, you can rewrite as $t(y'+y)'-(y'+y)=0$

Comment: Use Mike hine by letting $y'+y=g$, and then use the fact $
L\left\{ {t^n f\left( t \right)} \right\} = \left( { - 1} \right)^n \frac{{d^n }}{{ds^n }}F\left( s \right)$,where$F\left( s \right) = L\left\{ {f\left( t \right)} \right\}
$

Comment: @Mike Using your instructions I wounded up with a homogeneous first order linear ode: $G^{'}\left ( z \right )+\frac{2}{z}G\left ( z \right )=0$ which yields $G\left ( z \right )=\frac{C}{z^{2}}$, and thus $g\left ( t \right )= Ct$, where $C$ is an arbitrary real constant. How to proceed from here on?

Comment: Oh, now I see. The substitution we used is just another differential equation.

Comment: I got $y=5e^{-t}$ to be the particular solution. I tried putting the values in, and indeed, in the end we get an identity to hold. If anyone is willing just to check if that really is the solution, that would be great.

Comment: "Particular solution" is probably not the right term.  But the answer looks good.

Comment: So, just solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ty''(t)+(t-1)y'(t)-y(t)=0$

$t(y'(t)+y(t))'-(y'(t)+y(t))=0$

$\dfrac{(y'(t)+y(t))'}{y'(t)+y(t)}=\dfrac{1}{t}$

$\int\dfrac{(y'(t)+y(t))'}{y'(t)+y(t)}dt=\int\dfrac{1}{t}dt$

$\ln(y'(t)+y(t))=\ln t+c$

$y'(t)+y(t)=C_1t$

$(e^ty(t))'=C_1te^t$

$e^ty(t)=C_1(t-1)e^t+C_2$

$y(t)=C_1(t-1)+C_2e^{-t}$

$y(\infty)=0$ :

$C_1=0$

$\therefore y(t)=C_2e^{-t}$

$y(0)=5$ :

$C_2=5$

$\therefore y(t)=5e^{-t}$

Comment: Nice approach there.